# best way to make an ajax call to a PHP script, and have the reponse data opened in a new window.

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement a feature in my webapp to let user click a button and see a "status report" of something. The status report is quite large hence I want to have it on a separate page. I am trying to think of a way to make an Ajax call to a PHP script and have the response data displayed nicely on another window. Is there a way to do that? I am new to web dev and any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: whatever you do there's the potential that it will be blocked by popup blockers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sumbit a form with `target="_BLANK"`. That is don't make an AJAX call at all just a regular form sumbission triggered by javascript.

```
    var form=document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('action',url);
    form.setAttribute('target','_BLANK');
    form.setAttribute('method','post');
    form.setAttribute('style','display: none');

    var inp=document.createElement('input');
    inp.setAttribute('type','hidden');
    inp.setAttribute('name',item);
    inp.setAttribute('value',itemval);
    form.appendChild(inp);

    $('body').append(form);
    form.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not what ajax was made for.
When you open a new tab, server needs to send whole page anyway, there is no way to share HTML page between two tabs.
You can send report on page load or if sending asynchronously is necessary then try passing some GET variable which triggers ajax call from new tab.

Comment: Thanks for the help! but yeah i dont want to share html page on two tabs. Because so form everytime i submit a form it always redirect. So I just want to avoid that. THanks for the input though!